# Maximum ideal in field

Tags: field-theory

Let $k$ be a field, $n ∈ \mathbb{Z}>0$, and $α_1, α_2, ..., α_n ∈ k$. Prove: $(x_1 − α_1, x_2 − α_2, \ldots, x_n − α_n)$ is a maximal ideal.

I cannot figure out how to prove this; what is meant by the $x_i$? Are they subsets of $k$ or different unknown elements?

Comment: Are you familiar with the result that an ideal $I\subset R$ is maximal iff $R/I$ is a field? Also, to answer your last question: the $x_i$ are indeterminates. Think of them as variables. Try proving this for the toy model $(x-1) \subset \mathbb{R}[x]$. Can you show $(x-1)$ is maximal?

Comment: So R/(x-1) is a field because R/(x-1) is isomorphic to R,R/(x-1)={x-1+r|r element of R} which is isomorphic R. Therefore a field. So R/(x-1) is maximal.

Comment: You're right; but your identification $\mathbb{R}/(x-1) = \lbrace x+1+r\;|\;r\in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$ doesn't really sit right. It's better to think about setting $x=1$ and then $\mathbb{R}[x] \simeq \mathbb{R}[1] = \mathbb{R}$. You can do this, essentially, by long division: take a polynomial, and reduce it modulo $x-1$. This is exactly what is meant when you write the quotient $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x-1)$.

Comment: From your question it seems it isn't clear to you that you have to consider the polynomial ring $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n] $